# SVG Animations for dummies (AKA designers), or am trying too much

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'd like to be able to create animated SVG icons similar to this:
I can do this using Animate CC, or alternatively with After Effects. But I am not a coder, and this is way over my head.

I work at a company with a small team of devs and designers, and I would like to be able to hand off a prototype (either After Effects or Animate CC) to a dev that could do these things but I think it's not really something they would or could do.

Are there any programs that will create the code for you with a wysiwyg type editor?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source After Effects plugin called "bodymovin", which will let you export SVG animations.

https://github.com/bodymovin/bodymovin